# Email subscriptions to exchange groups

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I am attempting to set up a subscription on my report server that will send out an email to a outlook email group. However when I specify the group in the To: field on the report server I get the following email in response when the subscription is actually ran.

Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

Subject: Report was executed at 4/20/2011 9:39:02 AM

Sent: 4/20/2011 9:39 AM

The following recipient(s) cannot be reached

Outlook Email Group on 4/20/2011 9:39 AM

You do not have permission to send to this recipient. For assistance, contact your system administrator.

However, when I change the TO: to include members of that group they receive the emails fine. My question is, is it possible to specify out email group names in the TO: field of a report server subscription or do you have to put all of the individual email addresses of the members of that group in there for it to work? One of the responses that I got so far was: Consider that the Report Processor "logs on" with specific credentials. This is the Service Account. Try to open a Windows Session using these credentials and send the mail. I expect it will fail. Make sure this account has group-send rights.  Is this correct and if so should I be consulting with our exchange server admin to get group send rights added and to which user account?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that your group may be configured to only accept mail from authenticated users, but there are also other possibilities, for example it is also possible that the group has been configured to only accept mail from a certain set of users.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to put Exchange Group names into the SSRS recipient list.

I'm agree with your comment: this looks like an Exchange problem. Check with the mail admins to see what restrictions on mail to groups exist.

SSRS uses SMTP to send email. You can follow the instructions on Technet for [How to Use Telnet to Test SMTP...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx)  Substitute in the server name and from address that SSRS is set to use. You will likely see the test message refused with an error that will hopefully give you more details on the error. At the very least, it will give you something to take to the Exchange team. ( I don't believe that sending email from SSRS supports authentication, but I'm not sure on that.)

Comment: I have continued to try and resolve this issue but still have not had any success.  CUrrently the report server is set up to use the Local System as the service account.  If the instance is on my local machine and I am part of the domain and my user can send emails to this group through Outlook why can't I do it through SSRS?

Comment: I just edited my answer to provide details on the SMTP connection, which you can test.